# Automatic presenting View Controller

Tags: swift3

I have 2 view controllers on my storyboard: `viewController1`(it input point) and `viewController2`. After loading the application i want to automatic presenting `viewController2` after `viewController1`.

---

How i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to go to second viewcontroller you can add this code to you viewDidLoad method:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! secondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

remeber to add a identifier for the second viewcontroller in storyboard and chenge the identifier that you use with "yourIdentifier"

if you don't want a animation put the animated: true to false.

if you dont want to show the fist viewcontroller, go into you storyboard and click on the second viewcontroller, then in the right side on attributes inspector select the box int the image:

[image]

For change viewcontroller you have to embed the first viewcontroller with a navigation controller, if you don't know how to do it, just select the fisrt viewcontroller and do like the image, click in navigation controller

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show it in `func viewDidLoad() {}` like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to straight up load a different view controller you can do this in your app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "put your identifier here")
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    return true
}
```